# Widening and boxing with Java

Tags: java

In Java programming language widen and boxing doesn't work, but how does it work in following example?

```
final short myshort = 10;
Integer iRef5 = myshort;
```

Why does this work? Is this not the same as widen and then box?

But if I write the following code:

```
final int myint = 10;
Long myLONG = myint;
```

why it doesn't work?

Comment: What compiler are you using to get to your results? It seems to work with the Eclipse compiler, but not with the `javac` compiler

Comment: I am not able to get either one of them to work (using ideone.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With java 7 both the examples are not working. you will get below exception:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from short to Integer
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Long
```

Because the problem is not because of boxing  but because of conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Following what others have said, I can confirm that I can compile your first example with the Eclipse compiler, but not the second. With the `javac` compiler, both don't compile, as stated by Vlad

> This seems to be a bug in either compiler! Let's consult the JLS to find out, which one is right :-)

Comment: The eclipse compiler has some known and very subtle bugs that are not present on `javac`. I remember another one with the use of generics that left us wondering for a while.

Comment: @lsoliveira: You may be right, see also [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361513/reference-is-ambiguous-with-generics). However, it also happened the other way round in the past.

Comment: I guess that is always a possibility (although it never happened to me or anyone I know :-)).

Answer (score 1):

Neither works as it is (using javac 1.6.0_26 from Sun/Oracle, on Linux).
See also [here](http://ideone.com/6W7xi).

```
b.java:4: incompatible types
found   : short
required: java.lang.Integer
        Integer iRef5 = myshort; 
                        ^
b.java:7: incompatible types
found   : int
required: java.lang.Long
        Long myLONG = myint;
                      ^
2 errors
```

Comment: The first example works for me in Java 6 (Eclipse compiler)...?

Comment: Could it be they behave differently? I'm using Sun's compiler, see [here](http://ideone.com/6W7xi)

Comment: Could be. I've seen differences in the past, but not with such simple cases, see [this question, for instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361513/reference-is-ambiguous-with-generics)

Answer (score 1):

You can either widen or box, but you can't do both.

You can do

```
final int myint = 10;
Long myLONG = (long) myint;
```

Comment: There has to be a subtlety with implicit casting/promotion of `short` to `int` applied to the first example, before auto-boxing. Do you know by which rule?

Comment: `Object myLONG = 10L;` is perfectly valid

Comment: @LukasEder It doesn't compile for me as Vlad also states. ;)

Comment: @JigarJoshi I don't think widening a reference is what the OP means. `Long l = (Integer) 10;` doesn't compile.

Comment: `Long` and `Integer` are not in hierarchy to be widen

Comment: Jeez, I'm about to go crazy about those little differences between the `javac` and Eclipse compilers...

Comment: @JigarJoshi But `long` and `int` are.

Comment: you can do `int i = 10; long l = i; ` this is primitive widening but, if you do `Long l = 10;` this won't compile it should be long only with `L` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine what you're trying to do in detail:

```
final short myshort = 10;
Integer iRef5 = myshort;
```

The compiler will try to first box that short into an object, so that it can then perform the assignment (it cannot widen directly, since it is dealing with different types: an object and a primitive).

In short, this is equivalent to:

```
final short myshort = 10;
final Short box = new Short(myshort);  // boxing: so that objects are assignable.
Integer iRef5 = box;  // widening: this fails as Integer is not a superclass of Short
```

The same reasoning can be applied to your second example (which also fails), as is visible [here](http://www.ideone.com/g2JIs). If your compiler does not complain on the first one, then there might be a bug with the compiler, because this is what's defined in the JLS. See the complete set of rules for conversion/promotion in the JLS [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html).

Answer (score 0):

These are the promotion rules that apply to expressions in Java

all **byte** and **short** values are promoted to **int**

If one operand is **long**,the whole expression is promoted to **long**

If one operand is a **float** ,the whole expression is promoted to **float**

If one operand is **double** ,the whole expression is promoted to **double**

Hence short value is promoted to int. This is not widening.
**"The conversion of a subtype to one of its supertypes is called widening"**

---

Answer (score 0):

You can `box` then `wide` but you can't `widen` and then `box`

So

```
final short myshort = 10;
Integer iRef5 = myshort;
```

is equivalent to

```
final short myshort = 10;
Integer iRef5 = 10;
```

which is perfectly valid

but

```
Long myLONG = 10;//this won't compile ,
```

But try with `10L` it will so it will box then you can have it object too i.e. `Object o = 10L;`

---

**See also**

- [boxing-and-widening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995696/boxing-and-widening)
- [scjp-cant-widen-and-then-box-but-you-can-box-and-then-widen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720883/scjp-cant-widen-and-then-box-but-you-can-box-and-then-widen)

Comment: Are you sure the first example is perfectly valid? There seems to be a difference between the Eclipse compiler and the javac compiler. Which one is right?