# List all Java errors in JSP files

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, netbeans

I used old Eclipse (Helios) and old Tomcat (5.5) for a large web project. After updating to Tomcat 6, this code stopped working:

```
short foo = 3;
Integer bar = foo;
```

Apparently, this is invalid code according to the Java language specification[1], and there was a bug in the old Eclipse compiler so it didn't report it. New Eclipse (Kepler) reports it as an error.

I'm not quite sure why it stopped working with new Tomcat since it is using the same Java compiler as the old Tomcat, but the code is invalid and I want to fix it throughout the project.

First I tried validating the entire project in new Eclipse so it would list all .jsp files with this error. However, this validation in Eclipse doesn't seem to work very well since sometimes it detects several (existing) errors in a file and sometimes reports no errors in the same file (without changes, 10 seconds later).

Next thing I tried was to import project to NetBeans (7.4) and try to list those errors here. When I open a file with error, it detects it: "`incompatible types: short cannot be converted to Integer`". However, when I list all errors in the "Action Items" list, I can't find those errors (although I set the filter to include compiler errors).

I thought that listing all Java errors in all JSP files in a project would be easy, but turned out that it wasn't. How can I do it?

[1] [Widening and boxing with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601307/widening-and-boxing-with-java)

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: On dev machine where I'm trying to list all errors in NetBeans i'm using jdk1.7.0_45

Comment: What kind of project was it in Eclipse?

Comment: Almost every question about JSPs here contain Java code (scriptlets) in JSPs. And almost every answer tells not to use Java code in JSPs. Don't use Java code in JSPs. Use the JSP EL, the JSTL and other tags. Leave the Java code in your controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to compile all JSP files in the project (i.e. generate Java files for them) and then inspect errors for generated files.

NetBeans has option to pre-compile all JSP files, but this didn't work for me because it stops after it hits first Java file with errors (maybe there is a way to circumvent this?).

Another solution might be to configure Apache Maven to build entire project, but I didn't try this, because a co-worker came up with a nice quick-n-dirty solution:

Generate a wget request for every JSP file in project and run all these requests. It doesn't matter that wget can't really access the pages since it isn't logged in, it just 'touches' them and forces the Tomcat to generate Java files.

Something like this (linux/cygwin):

```
find jsp -name '*.jsp' -printf 'http://localhost:8080/App/%p\n' > tmp/urls
wget -q --proxy=off --spider -i tmp/urls
```