# Java left shift Operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

in java, char a=5 and using leftshift operator as println(a<<18) /* outcome: 262144 */  and it still giving further answers after 16 bit but it shouldnt because char in java is 16 bit. Why?

Comment: ... I really didn't understand what you said. What is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: `<<` will implicitly convert the `char` to an `int`

Comment: I get `1310720`. And from `a<<36` I get `80`.

Answer (score 2):

Left shift is applied to `int` or `long` operands. When you apply it to a `char` and an `int`, the `char` is promoted to an `int`, and the result is an `int`. Therefore 262144 is a valid result.

[**JLS 15.19. Shift Operators**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> The shift operators are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).
>
> **Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately**. (Binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is not performed on the operands.)
>
> It is a compile-time error if the type of each of the operands of a shift operator, after unary numeric promotion, is not a primitive integral type.
>
> **The type of the shift expression is the promoted type of the left-hand operand**.

Comment: Maybe change promoted to widened?

Comment: @Lino JLS says `Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately.`

Comment: you're right, got confused with [*boxing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995722/5515060)

Comment: Char as all other types are widened during conversion to int. It's good to say that int is the center of Java universe.

Comment: @MS90 - That's not really correct. Types are promoted to the closest bigger type. char is widened to int not because int is the center of java universe, but because it's the closest type which can handle a char (of course long could too, but it's too big and it would be unnecessary).

Comment: @BackSlash I agree to disagree that int is not the center of Java universe! All calculations/manipulations of bytes(!!!), shorts and chars are all widened to integer types during calculation. Considering that nearly almost everything in Java comes to subject mentioned above it is clear that int is the center of Java universe!